# How to change measuring units in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs

In a Google Docs document, I would like to be able to specify the page margins (File    → Page Setup) in millimeters instead of inches.

Is it possible to switch between imperial and metric units?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Go to Settings → Document Settings on the top right of the page and change the language to **English (UK)**.

Rulers and margins will now both be in centimetres (cm).

You may need to log out and sign back in before you see the changes take effect.

Comment: Changing language works but one should know that only new documents are affected.

Comment: I guess the setting is now located under "File" > "Language", or am I wrong?

Comment: Google should really decouple the preferences system. I live in Denmark so I measure my using the metric system and use DKK as currency, but I still want my interface to be in US English.

Comment: @grunwald2.0: In the new Google Docs, the account language affects the measuring system (located at myaccount.google.com/language). The document language can be set differently in "File → Language".

Comment: !!! this means that this answer is no longer correct! :( !!!

Comment: This no longer works.  See the answer from tanius instead.

Comment: @Jan Aagaard we can chose "English" then "Netherlands (yes it's absurd, but it goes with the usual Google's low quality work and don't-give-a-sh*t attitude)

Answer (score 55):

Due to recent changes, the measuring system in Google Docs is now affected by your Google Account default language, not anymore by the document language. (Means, [@Dominik's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/6547) no longer works.)

More precisely it's the country sub-setting that influences the measuring system now. And Google artificially limits country options depending on the chosen language.

So:

1. Go to [myaccount.google.com/language](https://myaccount.google.com/language). You can also reach it via the gear icon on the Google Drive or Google Docs main pages.
2. Set the language to "English – United Kingdom". (If it's currently "English – United States", click the pen icon, then again "English", then "United Kingdom". Bit counterintuitive.)
3. Reload your Google Docs document.

Voila: rulers and the "File → Page Setup… → Margins" settings are in centimeters now.

Comment: technically, this solves the problem of the OP, but it creates more. it is sad that Google took away the per-document setting.

Comment: "the measuring system in Google Docs is now affected by your Google Account default language" This is what I call a design mistake.

Comment: This should now be marked as the correct answer as the previously correct answer no longer applies.

Comment: @Kai it's the country subsetting of your default language that counts. google has partially decoupled language from country (lots of countries for english, few for german, ...)

Comment: NOTE: For anyone following this convoluted thread of changes it seems that the above mentioned fix works as a default for new documents, however there is now a setting for the document under File -> Language ... so it would seem they've listened, thank you Google!

Comment: Wow.  The fact the selection of units is hard-coded to language selection is pretty messed up.  By switching from US English to UK English you may find many other side effects such as different spelling suggestions (enrol vs enroll, etc).  It is crazy that google confuses language variant with which units you want to use.  Fine heuristic for default values but nonsense for many users.  It is like sites from some companies that won't let you switch to the english version because your geo-ip is currently Germany...so you must speak german...right?

Comment: There is only one "English", it seems, US, no UK one actually

Comment: The suggestion by @PaulCarroll of setting the per-document language under "File → Language → …" unfortunately does not work. It changes *just* the language, not the units. You really need to go to your account settings.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work. Setting everything to English UK (both account language and document language) and I'm still only offered antiquated units form the middle ages.

Comment: This didn't work for me.

Comment: It looks like the per-doc Language setting is back. I set my account language to English (Australia), but the Google slide was still set to English (US) and so I saw inches. I had to also set the doc to English (UK) to see "cm" not "in" but this slide is for a US audience and I want US spelling. Sad.

Comment: I chose "english" then Netherlands (even if I'm neither english nor from the Netherlands, because, why not?). It only works after reloading the doc.

Answer (score 8):

This is not possible in the current version of Google Docs with "English (US)" regional settings. Until they change this you can convert millimeters to inches using [this Google query](http://www.google.com/search?q=10mm%20in%20inches):

```
<n>mm in inches
```

Or you could follow the tips in Dominiks answer, and change your language settings to "English (UK)".

Comment: A helpful workaround.  However, the answer from Dominik no longer works.  See the answer from tanius instead.

Comment: there is no English UK language, only US

Answer (score 3):

To change the margins one can use File --> Page Layout --> Margins but doing so does not (for me at 2018-10-18) offer a change of the unit-of-measure of the margins.

Earlier answers show that this is influenced by the user's language.
(1) It used to be the language of the doc
(2) That was changed to the user's Google Account's language.

Well; I have set both to US English and have closed and opened the document but to no avail -- it stays at cm for me.

Here, though, is a low tech remedy: There are 2.54 cm to the inch. There is 0.39 inch to the cm. If the unit-of-measure stays stubbornly at the one you don't want, apply a conversion to get the desired margin. For example, I needed to have all four margins set to 1 inch, so set the value to 2.54 cm for each of the four.

Comment: Forget any manual corverting. The change in the settings just successfully applied to my document as well to my overall gAccount. (US-eng inches >> UK-eng cm) Just reload your doc to get the settings applied.

No doubt that the "simplification" was just stupid, from Google. :-/